# private array init returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am initializing a private NSMutableArray in an object, using the code developed in the BNR iOS objective C book. Here is the initialization code:

```
    //
//  NRCViewStore.m
//  Lifetimer
//
//  Created by Nelson Capes on 9/13/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Nelson Capes. All rights reserved.
//

#import "NRCViewStore.h"
#import "NRCView.h"
@interface NRCViewStore ()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *privateItems;
@end
@implementation NRCViewStore
+(instancetype)sharedStore
{
    static NRCViewStore *sharedStore;

    if(!sharedStore){
        sharedStore = [[self alloc]initPrivate];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initPrivate
{
    self = [super init];
    NSArray *viewList = @[@"seconds", @"minutes", @"hours",
                         @"months", @"days", @"years"];

    if(self){
        _privateItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:viewList];
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSArray *)allitems
{
    return [self.privateItems copy];
}


@end
```

However, when I call the object, the array that is returned is nil. The call to the object is this:

```
    #import "NRCViewStoreViewController.h"
#import "NRCViewStore.h"
#import "NRCView.h"

@implementation NRCViewStoreViewController
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count =[[[NRCViewStore sharedStore]allItems]count];
    return count;

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:@"NRCViewCell"];

    NSArray *array = [[NRCViewStore sharedStore]allItems];
    NRCView *view = array[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = view.viewName;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

As I understand the code, [NRCViewStore sharedStore] should do both alloc and init, and initialize the private NSMutableArray _privateItems. I set a breakpoint in initPrivate before return self and the _privateItems array is initialized as I want it. Then the call to -(NSArray *)allItems should return a copy of the initialized NSMutableArray that appears to the caller to be an NSArray. However, a breakpoint in the caller after the call to allitems shows that the returned array is nil. I can't figure this out because similar code in my other project (without the private array initialization) works.

Comment: Where's the second breakpoint? In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Which line?

Comment: I just moved _privateItems out of the class extension and into the class header and now the array is properly initialized!

Comment: @NelsonCapes - so, solved?